# Authentication via SFDC to "Approve" a record - Secure method needed

Tags: apex, visualforce, security, approval-process, authentication

I have a unique requirement to build and am having trouble with the method to use to meet it.

Working with a science lab that wants the ability to soft lock a record (via Validation Rule) that requires a user to re-authenticate in Salesforce to unlock the record. Sometimes the user doing the re-authentication is not the running user, but someone else in the lab. Think of it as a cashier at a supermarket who needs a special code for their cash register to approve a discount and they call the manager over.

Customer is using Lightning on Enterprise.

So, on a Sample record the running user will be alerted that they need to authenticate recent field changes. They will call over a colleague to authenticate the record. Either user will then click an Action button on the record. That will launch a window with user authentication available (user/pass). If the user is able to authenticate, it will capture the authenticating user's name and date/time on the original record, without de-authenticating the original user.

Essentially, the second user will need to start a second session. Proper security is important to this lab as there are regulations in place.

Possible Tooling:

1. VisualForce Page and APEX - is this secure enough?
2. Flow with a Lighnting web component to handle authentication?
3. Approval Process with Chatter or Email Approvals?

To preserve the speed of the workflow in the lab, we would prefer a solution that doesn't require too many devices. Also, some devices like mobile phones aren't allowed in certain labs, so a mobile requirement isn't optimal.

**Question:** Is this requirement feasible? Is there a tool already built that would handle this without custom development? If custom dev is needed, is VisualForce/APEX the best tool to use here? Are there technical/security concerns to consider that I haven't covered above?

Comment: so - within the first user's session, you are trying to have a second user enter their credentials , have those credentials verified, so the first user's session can proceed?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). While you could accomplish this as stated with custom dev, what you want to do is rethink the problem vs solution. Problem: approval of changes. Out of the box solution: workflow where changes are not committed until approved by 2nd user in their own session.